Person has no house number on Census, but two different house numbers on Electoral Rolls (19th Century UK)
On the 1849-50 Register of Voters, Charles Ashmore in Manchester, UK was listed at 331 Rochdale Road.

On the 1850-51 Register of Voters, he was listed at 329 Rochdale Road. 
And on the 1851 Census, Charles Ashmore doesn't have a house number, but is listed in between 331 and 329 Rochdale Road.  His job is "proprietor of houses".  I'm curious as to what all this could mean, where did he actually live?
I could not find Rochdale Road Police Station on historical maps, which could possibly help.


There could be a number of scenarios. These houses would have been adjacent - maybe he moved next door. Maybe 329 and 331 were even joined as typical UK style town/terrace houses. If they had been converted to lodgings it's entirely possible that he was the proprietor of them both and he split his time equally between them. I see from Google maps that Rochdale Road still exists but in that section has a wide berm where a row of houses could have once been.

Where have you looked for historical maps? Have you consulted the collection at the National Library of Scotland, which holds OS maps for much of the UK? What about Post Office and trade directories?

@JanMurphy I looked on the National Library of Scotland and couldn't find a Police Station.  Where do I find Post Office maps and trade directories?

Historical Directories of England and Wales at U Leicester: https://specialcollections.le.ac.uk/digital/collection/p16445coll4 (free) or on pay sites like Ancestry or THe Genealogist.
